# javascript preappend to load new div to the side of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this jfiddle works fine but it loads the content vertically, I want to be able to load each new div to the side of the other to create a long horizontal list of divs. How can I do this? thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/mxadam/Mdzmx/45/

html

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="content">

</div>
</div>


<button id="create" onclick="createDiv()">create</button>
<button id="create2" onclick="createDiv2()">create2</button>
```

css

```
#wrap{ height: 200px; position:relative; overflow-x:scroll;}
#content{height: 200px; position: absolute; bottom:0; left:0}
#child{height: 100%;width: 200px;background-color: #000;float:left;}
```

javascript

```
function createDiv(){
$('#content').prepend('<div id="div" style="height: 100%;width: 200px;background-color: rgb(0,114,157);">div1</div>');
}

function createDiv2(){
$('#content').prepend('<div id="div2" style="height: 100%;width: 200px;background-color: #000;">div2</div>');
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to layout columns across the page.  The most common is using `float:left`.  If you search for "css columns", you will find a zillion web pages on the topic.

Comment: thanks for the edit jfriend, dont know how i missed that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the child elements `inline-block` as opposed to `block`.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/29vLF/)

```
#content > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Alternatively you could [float them too](http://jsfiddle.net/xf84F/).

It would be best to use the `inline-block` approach because you could then add `white-space:nowrap` to the parent element to prevent the elements from wrapping to a new line.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xCMd2/)

Comment: thanks joshc perfect! will accept once allowed - 10min